# PHP Cut specific string

Tags: php, regex

hy I want grab every filename for example :
I have data

```
01.jpg02.jpg03.jpg10599335_899600036724556_4656814811345726851_n.jpg11693824_1051832718167953_6310308040295800037_n.jpg11709788_1051835281501030_8503525152567309473_n.jpg12042832_1103685106316047_3711793359145824637_n.jpg
```

I'm try like this but not working for me

```
$str = $_POST['name'];
print_r (explode(".jpg", $str));
foreach ($str as $key => $value) {
echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to grab files with extension like `10599335_899600036724556_4656814811345726851_n.jpg` ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, how do that

Comment: First of all why don`t you post as an ARRAY?

Comment: Do any of the provided answers work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all` function:

```
$str = "01.jpg02.jpg03.jpg10599335_899600036724556_4656814811345726851_n.jpg11693824_1051832718167953_6310308040295800037_n.jpg11709788_1051835281501030_8503525152567309473_n.jpg12042832_1103685106316047_3711793359145824637_n.jpg";

preg_match_all("/(?<=\.jpg)?\w+\.jpg/", $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01.jpg
    [1] => 02.jpg
    [2] => 03.jpg
    [3] => 10599335_899600036724556_4656814811345726851_n.jpg
    [4] => 11693824_1051832718167953_6310308040295800037_n.jpg
    [5] => 11709788_1051835281501030_8503525152567309473_n.jpg
    [6] => 12042832_1103685106316047_3711793359145824637_n.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookbehind regex in `preg_match_all`:

```
/(?<=^|\.jpg)\w+\.jpg/
```

Lookbehind asserts that our match has a preceding `.jpg` or line start.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY6kZ0/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/(?<=^|\.jpg)\w+\.jpg/m'; 

preg_match_all($re, $input, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/x1ajal)

Answer (score 0):

The explode takes the delimited value off so you would need to re-append it.

```
$filenames = explode('.jpg', '01.jpg02.jpg03.jpg10599335_899600036724556_4656814811345726851_n.jpg11693824_1051832718167953_6310308040295800037_n.jpg11709788_1051835281501030_8503525152567309473_n.jpg12042832_1103685106316047_3711793359145824637_n.jpg');
foreach($filenames as $file) {
    if(!empty($file)) {
         echo $file . ".jpg\n";
    }
}
```

https://eval.in/596532

A regex approach that I think would work is:

```
(.*?\.jpg)
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/gR7rC5/1

PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*?\.jpg)/', '01.jpg02.jpg03.jpg10599335_899600036724556_4656814811345726851_n.jpg11693824_1051832718167953_6310308040295800037_n.jpg11709788_1051835281501030_8503525152567309473_n.jpg12042832_1103685106316047_3711793359145824637_n.jpg', $filenames);
foreach($filenames[1] as $file) {
    echo $file . "\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/596530

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?\.jpg)/", $str, $out);
Var_dump($out[1]);
```

Click preg_match_all
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gcR